# Implementing an Interface with an abstract method

Tags: java, implementation

I am trying to implement an interface using `public class MyStringSet implements StringSet{}` but I keep getting an error that "MyStringSet is not abstract and does not override abstract method getCapacity() in StringSet". How would I be able to impletment this interface without getting this error?

```
    public interface StringSet {
         public void resize(int larger);
         public void insert(String entry);
         public void remove(String target);                  
         public String getRandomItem ();           
         public String getFirstItem ();         
         public boolean contains(String target);                
         public boolean is_empty( );                   
         public int inventory( );                  
         public int getCapacity( );
    }
```

Comment: What problem do you have to implement this method?

Comment: Either add default definitions to these methods or make MyStringSet abstract.

Comment: Please add your `MyStringSet` class. Surely it doesn't contain the required `getCapacity()` method.

Comment: What problems do you have with an error message as clear as that? If it says that your class "MyStringSet [...] does not override abstract method getCapacity() in StringSet", then simply do that! Override it. I voted to close as unclear.

Comment: I guess it's a beginner's question. I guess there are plenty of these guys learning Java and having the same question. He implemented an interface by using the implements keyword. So why is the compiler complaining he forgot something? You have to know, what is overriding to understand the message. Maybe my example down there helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: most likely, your implementation is not really "implementing" those abstract methods. An interface is like holes. The implementation fills those holes and if not, you have to declare your extending class as abstract, as it let some of those "holes" open. They still have to be filled by a real implementation which is not abstract anymore.

Here is an easy implementation for your case:

```
public class MyStringSet implements StringSet {
  public void resize(int larger) {}
  public void insert(String entry) {}
  public void remove(String target) {}
  public String getRandomItem () {return null;}
  public String getFirstItem () {return null;}
  public boolean contains(String target) {return false;}
  public boolean is_empty( ) {return false;}
  public int inventory( ) {return 0;}
  public int getCapacity( ) {return 0;}
}
```