# How to get the data from a file into an array?

Tags: java

Over the passed couple of hours I have been working on an assigment with no luck in figuring it out. For reference I am going to post the instructions below and then explain what I have done.

> Write a Java class that implements the StringSet interface (see
> attached text document). One of your instance variables must be an
> array of Strings that holds the data; you may determine what, if any
> other instance variables you need. You will also need to implement the
> required methods, one or more constructors, and any other methods you
> deem necessary. I have also provided a tester class that you should be
> able to run your code with.

So far I have created an implementation of the interface named MyStringSet. I have put all of the methods from the interface into my implementation and have written the code to what I think will work. My main problem is that I don't know how to put the data from the main method that is called into an array. The user types in a file and and then it is supposed to return word count and other methods. Since the file is being called from the tester class, I need to store that data into an array or an array list which I have already created. Below I have listed my current implementation and the tester class that I use. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My Implementation:

```
public class MyStringSet implements StringSet {
  String[] myArray = new String [] {};
  List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(myArray);
  
  //default constructor
  public MyStringSet(){
   resize(5);
    }

  // precondition: larger is larger than current Set size
  // postcondition: enlarges Set
  public void resize(int larger) {
      myArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length + larger);
    }
  
  // postcondition: entry is inserted in Set if identical String
  // not already present; if identical entry exists, takes no
  // action.  Calls resize if necessary
  public void insert(String entry) {
    
    Set<String> myArray = new HashSet<String>();
    Collections.addAll(myArray, entry);
    
    
    }

  // postcondition:  removes target value from Set if target is
  // present; takes no action otherwise
  public void remove(String target) {
    if(target != null){
        int n = 0;
        int index = n;
        for(int i = index; i < myArray.length - 1; i++) {
        myArray[i] = myArray[i+1];
    }
}
}
    
  // precondition: Set is not empty
  // postcondition: A random String is retrieved and removed from
  // the Set
  public String getRandomItem () {
      String s = "String is Empty";
    if (myArray != null) {
        int rnd = new Random().nextInt(myArray.length);
        return myArray[rnd];
    }
    
    else {
        return s ;
    }
    }
  
  // precondition: Set is not empty
  // postcondition: the first item in the Set is retrieved and
  // removed from the Set
  public String getFirstItem () { 
    String firstItem = myList.get(0);
    return firstItem;
    }
  
  // postcondition: returns true if target is present, false
  // if not
  public boolean contains(String target) {
      if (target == null) {
        return false;
        
        }
      else {
        return true;
        }
    }
  
  // postcondition: returns true if Set is empty, false if not
  public boolean is_empty( ) {
    if(myArray == null){
        return true;
    
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    }
  
   // postcondition: returns total number of Strings currently in set
  public int inventory() {
      int total = myList.size();
      return total;
    }
  
  // postcondition: returns total size of Set (used & unused portions)
  public int getCapacity( ) {
    int capacity = myArray.length;
    return capacity;
    }
}
```

Tester class:

```
public class SetTester
{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        StringSet words = new MyStringSet();
        Scanner file = null;
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        String input;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int wordCt = 0;
        
        boolean ok = false;
        
        while (!ok)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter name of input file: ");
            input = kb.nextLine();
            try
            {
                fs = new FileInputStream(input);
                ok = true;
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println(input + " is not a valid file.  Try again.");
            }
        }
        
        file = new Scanner(fs);
        while (file.hasNext())
        {
            input = file.next();
            words.insert(input);
            System.out.println("Current capacity: " + words.getCapacity());  
            wordCt++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("There were " + wordCt + " words in the file");
        System.out.println("There are " + words.inventory() + " elements in the set");
        System.out.println("Enter a value to remove from the set: ");
        input = kb.nextLine();
        while (!words.contains(input))
        {
            System.out.println(input + " is not in the set");
            System.out.println("Enter a value to remove from the set: ");
            input = kb.nextLine();
        }
        
        words.remove(input);
        System.out.println("There are now " + words.inventory() + " elements in the set");
        System.out.println("The first 10 words in the set are: ");
        for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
            System.out.println(words.getFirstItem());
        System.out.println("There are now " + words.inventory() + " elements in the set");
        System.out.println("5 random words from the set are: ");
        for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
            System.out.println(words.getRandomItem());
        System.out.println("There are now " + words.inventory() + " elements in the set");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an array and a list?

Comment: @oneCricketeer There's no specific reason, I am just lost and didn't know what else to try. What would be a better option?

Comment: `ArrayList` contains an array internally, so you dont need both or to copy values between the two... But the instructions state _One of your instance variables must be an array of Strings_, so I would remove the List

Comment: In any case, I would forget the file for now and create a [mcve] of just inserting data correctly into your class manually

Comment: @OneCricketeer not a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323520/implementing-an-interface-with-an-abstract-method `StringSet` appears a few times in different SO questions.

Comment: @Abra I didnt say anything about duplicates

Answer (score 0):

> main problem is that I don't know how to put the data from the main method that is called into an array

You're doing that correctly already, following this simple example

```
StringSet words = new MyStringSet();
words.insert("something");
```

However, the contents of the insert method seem incorrect 1) you never check for identical values 2) never resizing 3) `Collections.addAll` doesn't do what you want, most likely

So, with those in mind, and keeping an array, you should loop over it, and check where the next non-null, non-identical value would be placed

```
// postcondition: entry is inserted in Set if identical String
// not already present; if identical entry exists, takes no
// action.  Calls resize if necessary
public void insert(String entry) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < myArray.length && myArray[i] != null) {
       if (myArray[i].equals(entry)) return; // end function because found matching entry
       i++;
    }
    if (i >= myArray.length) {
        // TODO: resize()

        insert(entry); // retry inserting same entry into larger array
    }
    // updates the next non-null array position
    myArray[i] = entry;
}
```

As far as displaying the MyStringSet class goes, to see the contents of the array, you'll want to add a `toString` method